# How to make a triggered object stop moving when colliding with another object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, unity3d-2dtools

I'm having trouble with a gameobject that i'm actually dragging and its box collider is triggered due to some functions that I need to make. The problem is that I don't know how to block this gameobject from moving beyond another gameobject, that is colliding with.

```
//This is my object drag, might help.. it's a .cs code attached to the game object
void OnMouseDrag()
{
    Vector3 curScreenPoint = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z);
    Vector3 curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenPoint) + offset;
    if (Global.noGrid[0]) //noGrid means inside the grid ('no' in Portuguese means 'in')
    {
        transform.position = Global.FindClosestObject(curPosition, "gizmo_peca").transform.position; // here i find the game closest gameobject inside the grid, i do that because i need a snap (that's why i need the trigger working to, to recognize which gameobject it's colliding
    }
    else
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(curPosition.x, curPosition.y, curPosition.z);
    }

}

// This is what i tried but with no success in BlockForma.cs (It's how I call my gameobject above)
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D c)
{

    if (c.tag == "Forma")
    {
        c.rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(0,0);
        Debug.Log("Hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add what have you tried so far(i.e: code)?

Comment: I had problems posting the code here so here's a [LINK](http://pastebin.com/cgr8i46p) with the code commented, if you need anything else just let me know.

Comment: Have you attached a collider and a rigidbody component to the gameobject which tag is "Forma"?

Comment: Yeah, I think the problem may be this: transform.position = Global.FindClosestObject(curPosition, "gizmo_peca").transform.position;

Answer (score 1):

This solution is tested and it's 100% works.

if you want to stop game object then,

```
rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.zero;
```

if you want to stop collide object then ,

```
col.rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.zero;
```